# Python Export Report Microsoft Access using win32com.client

Tags: python, ms-access, pywin32, win32com

I have some reports in Access format and I want to generate PDF of these reports from Python script.

I read a lot of questions and answers about how to do it and came up with this simple script.

My code is:

```
import win32com.client as win
import os
access = win.Dispatch("Access.Application")
db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(filename)
access.DoCmd.OpenReport(report_name,2)
access.DoCmd.OutputTo(3, report_name, r'PDF Format (*.pdf)','c:/temp/test.pdf' )
access.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
access.Quit()
access=None
```

Executing the script first time gives this error (translate for me in English):

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'An exception occurred.', (0, None, ' Cannot execute this action now.', None, -1, -2146825802), None)
```

And file Access is open.

The second time I execute, it says `The database is already open.`
When I close the Access and execute it gives the first error again.

UPDATE: Now I change my code for closing database while script is executing and is the second time I executed, and then the scripts works fine.

```
import win32com.client as win
import os
import time
def file_open(file_name):
        if os.path.exists(file_name):
                try:
                        os.rename(file_name, file_name) #can't rename an open file so an error will be thrown
                        return False
                except:
                        print("File Open "+file_name)
                        time.sleep(2)
                        file_open(file_name)
                        return True
        else:
                return False
        raise NameError
access = win.Dispatch("Access.Application")
file_open(filename)
db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(filename)
access.DoCmd.OpenReport(report_name,2)
if os.path.isfile('c:/temp/test.pdf'):
    os.remove('c:/temp/test.pdf')
access.DoCmd.OutputTo(3, report_name, r'PDF Format (*.pdf)','c:/temp/test.pdf' )
access.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
access.Quit()
access=None
```

After this correct execution, if I executed another time I have the first error. I execute for second time and then works fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find this solution. It's not better, but it works. If someone have a better solution please let me now.

The solution is kill MSACCESS process in windows.

This is my code:

```
import win32com.client as win
import os

access = win.Dispatch("Access.Application")
db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(filename)
access.DoCmd.OpenReport(report_name,2)
if os.path.isfile('c:/temp/test.pdf'): # Delete previous PDF
    os.remove('c:/temp/test.pdf')
access.DoCmd.OutputTo(3, report_name, r'PDF Format (*.pdf)','c:/temp/test.pdf' )
access.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
os.system("taskkill /im MSACCESS.exe") # Kill process in wondows
```

Comment: Just a small remark: when you setup your Access DB with compact and repair at closing, your task kill could bring problems as compact can take some seconds depending on the database size and location (local vs network).

Answer (score 1):

`access.Quit()` doesn't really close the ms access file/db. You also need to delete the reference to the ms access file/db via `del access`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).